# Replace missing "NA" values by binding rows with matching attributes in R

Tags: r, bind, missing-data

I'm dealing with a large dataset that has some cleanliness issues. For your sanity, I've produced a much simpler example. Let's say the dataset looks like this:

```
  A        B       C     D     E     F     G     H
1 Albania  2015    10    NA    NA    NA    60    NA
2 Albania  2015    NA    NA    50    NA    NA    10
3 Greece   2016    30    NA    20    NA    NA    NA
4 Greece   2016    NA   400    NA    30    30    10
5 Greece   2017    NA    40    NA    NA    NA    NA
6 Greece   2017    20    NA    30    30    50    10
7 Albania  2015    NA   200    NA    40    NA    NA
```

Excuse the complexity, but I'm hoping a solution will work for my practical application. As you can see, duplicate entries of rows (eg Albania 2015) have caused the variable observations to be spread across multiple rows. I'm looking to bind rows with matching string values in the first two columns (country and year) and unify the spread out variable values (C-H) into a single row. In the end, the data frame should look like this:

```
  A           B     C     D     E     F     G     H
1 Albania  2015    10   200    50    40    60    10
2 Greece   2016    30   400    20    30    30    10
3 Greece   2017    20    40    30    30    50    10
```

Can someone carry me to a solution here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'A', 'B', and `summarise` the rest of the columns with one of the functions `max/sum/min` as there is only a single non-NA element for each column/group

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(A, B) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA
         else max(., na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 3 x 8
# Groups:   A [2]
#  A           B     C     D     E     F     G     H
#  <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 Albania  2015    10   200    50    40    60    10
#2 Greece   2016    30   400    20    30    30    10
#3 Greece   2017    20    40    30    30    50    10
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("Albania", "Albania", "Greece", "Greece", 
"Greece", "Greece", "Albania"), B = c(2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2015L), C = c(10L, NA, 30L, NA, NA, 20L, NA), D = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 400L, 40L, NA, 200L), E = c(NA, 50L, 20L, NA, NA, 30L, 
NA), F = c(NA, NA, NA, 30L, NA, 30L, 40L), G = c(60L, NA, NA, 
30L, NA, 50L, NA), H = c(NA, 10L, NA, 10L, NA, 10L, NA)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Comment: This worked! One last question-- what happens if there's mistakenly 2 different values/duplicate entries for the same match? Is there a way to select only 1 value (say, the max/min value) by default?

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020  The `max` would select the single `max` value by default

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020  You can check `max(c(50, 50, 20, NA), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020  Updated the comments